# Local WebRTC Unity to JS Client for Monodirectional Video

Tags: javascript, node.js, unity-game-engine, webrtc

The direction is Unity --> JavaScript, where Unity is capturing video.
Using WebRTC the Unity and JavaScript clients are able to communicate to each other, but it seems that the JavaScript client cannot display any video being sent by the Unity client.

I do not know why the JavaScript client cannot display any video output despite having clear communication (i.e receiving).

I've tried changing/adding a codec to now avail, but I'm not sure if I need to since the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.webrtc@2.4/manual/videostreaming.html#video-codec) (Unity WebRTC 2.4.0) don't really specify that a codec is need. I am using [NativeWebSocket](https://github.com/endel/NativeWebSocket) (a C# library) to communicate to my local server. SDPs are able to be sent from both clients, but (again) there seems to be no video displaying on my JavaScript client.

Unity Client

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.WebRTC;
using System;
using NativeWebSocket;

public class LocalMediaSender : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera capture_camera;
    private RTCPeerConnection local_connection;
    private RTCDataChannel data_channel;
    private WebSocket ws;
    public string ip = "192.168.X.X"; // TODO: add your IP here
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    async void Start()
    {
        ws = new WebSocket($"ws://{ip}:8080");
        ws.OnOpen += () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Connection open!");
            InitializeWebRTC();
        };

        ws.OnError += (e) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Error! " + e);
        };

        ws.OnClose += (e) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Connection closed!");
        };

        ws.OnMessage += (bytes) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("OnMessage!");
            Debug.Log(bytes);

            // Getting the message as a string
            var message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            Debug.Log("OnMessage! " + message);

            // Deserialize the message to SDPMessage
            SDPMessage sdpMessage = JsonUtility.FromJson<SDPMessage>(message);

            // Check if the message is an answer
            if (sdpMessage.type == "answer")
            {
                // Create a RTCSessionDescription for the answer
                RTCSessionDescription answer = new RTCSessionDescription
                {
                    type = RTCSdpType.Answer,
                    sdp = sdpMessage.sdp
                };

                // Start the coroutine to set the remote description for the local connection
                StartCoroutine(HandleSetRemoteDescription(answer));
            }
        };


        await ws.Connect();
    }

    private void InitializeWebRTC()
    {
        // [Step 1] Create Peer Connection
        local_connection = new RTCPeerConnection(/*ref config*/);

        /* ADD EVENT HANDLERS */
        {
            // [Step 2] onopen Connection Notification
            RTCDataChannelInit init = new RTCDataChannelInit { ordered = true }; // to ensure that data packets are delivered in order makes it reliable
            data_channel = local_connection.CreateDataChannel("myChannel", init);
            data_channel.OnOpen += () =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Data Channel Opened -- Unity");
            };

            // [Step 3] onicecandidate To Print SDP
            local_connection.OnIceCandidate = (e) =>
            {
                string iceCandidateString = JsonUtility.ToJson(e);
                // Inside the OnIceCandidate event handler in Unity
                ws.SendText(iceCandidateString);
                //Debug.Log("[ICE Candidate] " + iceCandidateString);
            };
        }

        // [Step 4] addTrack Video Media To Send
        if (capture_camera == null){ Debug.LogError("[ERROR] There is no camera!"); }
        MediaStream video_stream_track = capture_camera.CaptureStream(1280, 720);
        foreach (var track in video_stream_track.GetTracks()) { 
            local_connection.AddTrack(track, video_stream_track);
        }

        // [Step 5] createOffer 
        // use button to start offer
    }


    public void StartOffer() {
        StartCoroutine(HandleCreateOffer());
    }

    public void StopOffer() {
        StopCoroutine(HandleCreateOffer());
    }

    IEnumerator HandleCreateOffer()
    {
        RTCOfferAnswerOptions offerOptions = default;

        var op = local_connection.CreateOffer(ref offerOptions);
        yield return op;

        if (op.IsError)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Error creating offer: {op.Error}");
            yield break;
        }

        RTCSessionDescription offer = op.Desc;
        offer.sdp = offer.sdp.Replace("m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102", "m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96");

        // [Step 6] setLocalDescription Once Offer Is Successful
        var setLocalDescOp = local_connection.SetLocalDescription(ref offer);
        yield return setLocalDescOp;

        if (setLocalDescOp.IsError)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Error setting local description: {setLocalDescOp.Error}");
        }
        else
        {
            // Send local_description after it has been set
            if (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                //string sdp_string = JsonUtility.ToJson(local_connection.LocalDescription);
                string sdp_string = JsonUtility.ToJson(new SDPMessage { sdp = local_connection.LocalDescription.sdp, type = local_connection.LocalDescription.type.ToString() });
                ws.SendText(sdp_string);
                Debug.Log("[SDP] " + sdp_string);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("WebSocket connection is not open.");
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator HandleSetRemoteDescription(RTCSessionDescription answer)
    {
        var op = local_connection.SetRemoteDescription(ref answer);
        yield return op;

        if (op.IsError)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Error setting remote description: {op.Error}");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Remote description set successfully.");
        }
    }


    [Serializable]
    public class SDPMessage
    {
        public string sdp;
        public string type;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // required to recieve messages from signaling server
        #if !UNITY_WEBGL || UNITY_EDITOR
                ws.DispatchMessageQueue();
        #endif
    }
}
```

JavaScript Client

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Local WebRTC Receiver</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Create a video element to display the remote video stream -->
    <video 
        style="box-sizing: border-box; border: 5px solid black;" 
        id="remote-video" 
        autoplay 
        playsinline 
        width="1280" 
        height="720">
        <!-- video body -->
    </video>

    <script>
        let ip = "192.168.X.X" // TODO: add your IP here
        
        const local_connection = new RTCPeerConnection();
        let offer = null;
        

        // Connect to the WebSocket signaling server
        const signalingServer = new WebSocket(`ws://${ip}:8080`);

        signalingServer.onopen = (e) =>{ /* when connected */ }
        
        signalingServer.onmessage = (event) => {
            event.data.text().then((msg)=>{
                console.log("De-Blobed Message:", msg);
                const message = JSON.parse(msg);
                console.log("JSON Message:", message);

                // Answer offer
                if(message.type == "Offer"){
                    offer = message;
                    offer.type = "offer"; // <-- THIS IS DUMB BUT NEEDED

                    local_connection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer))
                        .then((e)=>{
                            console.log("offer set!");
                            return local_connection.createAnswer();
                        })
                        .then((answer)=>{
                            console.log("setting local description!");
                            return local_connection.setLocalDescription(answer);
                        })
                        .then((e)=>{
                            console.log("Sending Local Description")
                            const sdp = local_connection.localDescription;
                            signalingServer.send(JSON.stringify(sdp));
                        })
                        .catch((err)=>{console.error(err);})
                }
                
                // Handle incoming messages (ICE candidates, offers, etc.)
            })

        };

      local_connection.onicecandidate = (e) =>{
        console.log("[SDP] ", local_connection.localDescription);
      };


      local_connection.ontrack = (e) =>{
        console.log("Received remote track:", e.track);
        console.log("Received remote streams:", e.streams);
        console.log("Kind:", e.track.kind);

        if(e.track.kind == "video"){            
            // Display the remote video stream in the video element
            const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remote-video');
            remoteVideo.srcObject = e.streams[0];

            console.log(remoteVideo.srcObject);
            console.log("Codec: ",e.track.getSettings().codec);
            console.log("Settings: ",e.track.getSettings());
        }
        
      };

      local_connection.ondatachannel = (e) =>{
        var receiveChannel = ev.channel;

        receiveChannel.onmessage = (e) =>{
            console.log("[Message from Unity]\n",e.data);
        };
        
        receiveChannel.onopen = (e) =>{
            console.log("Connected! -- JS");
        };

        receiveChannel.onclose = (e) =>{ /* when connection closes*/ };
      }
 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Node JS Server

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const host_ip = "192.168.X.X" // TODO: add your IP here
const server = new WebSocket.Server({ host: host_ip, port: 8080 });

const clients = new Set();

server.on("connection", (socket) => {
  clients.add(socket);
  console.log("[Server] Client connected");

  socket.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log("-=-=-=-=-=-[New Message Received]-=-=-=-=-=-");
    console.log(message.toString())
    console.log("-=-=-=-=-=-[END Message Received]-=-=-=-=-=-");

    // console.log("Received:", message);

    // Broadcast the message to all other clients
    for (const client of clients) {
      if (client !== socket) {
        client.send(message);
      }
    }
  });

  socket.on("close", () => {
    clients.delete(socket);
    console.log("[Server] Client disconnected");
  });
});

console.log(`[Server] WebSocket signaling server running on ws://${host_ip}:8080`);
```

To run the server make sure to have Node.JS installed and then run `npm i` and `npm start`. Also ensure you add the host's (computer where server will be running on) IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, you have to set the codec for your video

I've changed your code in unity like this :

```cs
// [Step 4] addTrack Video Media To Send
        if (capture_camera == null) { Debug.LogError("[ERROR] There is no camera!"); }
        MediaStream video_stream_track = capture_camera.CaptureStream(1280, 720);
        foreach (var track in video_stream_track.GetTracks())
        {
            var videoSender = local_connection.AddTrack(track, video_stream_track);
            if (WebRTCSettings.UseVideoCodec != null)
            {
                var transceiver = local_connection.GetTransceivers().First(t => t.Sender == videoSender);
                var codecs = RTCRtpSender.GetCapabilities(TrackKind.Video).codecs;
                var h264Codecs = codecs.Where(codec => codec.mimeType == "video/H264");
                var error = transceiver.SetCodecPreferences(h264Codecs.ToArray());
                if (error != RTCErrorType.None)
                    Debug.LogError("SetCodecPreferences failed");
            }
        }
```

Hope this help !